# Get error to my nextjs project adding a listener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Add a listener for the "auth:verification-id" event
    const { data: listener}:
      { data: { subscription: Subscription, unsubscribe: () => void } } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
        async (event: string, session: any) => {
          console.log(event, session);
          if (event === 'SIGNED_IN' && session?.user?.email_verified) {
            router.push('/profile-upgrade');
          }
        }
      );
  
    // Unsubscribe the listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      listener?.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

```
TypeError: listener.unsubscribe is not a function

Type '{ data: { subscription: Subscription; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ data: { subscription: Subscription; unsubscribe: () => void; }; }'.
  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type '{ subscription: Subscription; }' but required in type '{ subscription: Subscription; unsubscribe: () => void; }'.ts(2322)
index.tsx(18, 45): 'unsubscribe' is declared here.
```

maybe someone can explain how I can fix this error?

I want the user gets redirected to the `/profile-upgrade` page when confirming the email.

Comment: So it looks like there is no `unsubscribe()` method on the `listener` object.  You should see what the `listener` object has on it by either debugging or adding a `console.log(listener)` in there so you can see what you are actually getting back.

Comment: Looks like a name collision on listener, is there another listener thats imported from another file ?